# Adding a button to each cell in fullcalendar to allow user to add an event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have been using jQuery along with fullcalendar to create a calendar that displays events from a database using php and MYSQL.

The calendar looks like this.

[image]

The events are shown in red. I would like to be able to add a button in each of the cells that do not have an event to allow the user to be able to add one.

Here is the code I have tried

```js
viewRender: function (view) {
   $(".fc-content").append('<button>Add</button>')  
   }
```

my full code.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 const calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'

  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00',
  allDaySlot: false,
  scrollTime: '09:00',
  businessHours: {
    dow: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], 
    start: '09:00', 
    end: '17:30'
  },

  //viewRender: function (view) {
                  //  $(".fc-content").append('<button>Book</button>');
                      //  },
  
  long: /^en-/.test(navigator.language) ? 'en' : 'zh-cn',
  eventOverlap: (stillEvent, movingEvent) => {
   return true;
  }, 
  events:
    <?php echo $json;?>

     //'2018-12-12T15:00+08:00'
  //}, 
  //{
   //title: '',
   //start: '' //'2018-12-12T12:00+08.00'
  ,
  eventColor: '#FF0000',
  edittable: true,
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  select: (start, end) => {
   const duration = (end - start) / 1000;
    if(duration == 1800){
     // set default duration to 1 hr.
     end = start.add(30, 'mins');
     return
    calendar.fullCalendar('select', start, end);
    }
    let eventData;
    if (title && title.trim()) {
     eventData = {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end
     };
    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData);
    }

    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

  },
   eventRender: (event, element) => {
    const start = moment(event.start).fromNow();
    element.attr('title', start);

   },

     loading: () => {}
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you intend to add the event when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: it will be adding to a mysql database using php

Comment: You'll need to supply start time, title etc using a form to insert it to the database. You've missed that part in your code above.

Comment: yes but without the button to click the module for that stuff can't be displayed

Comment: There are already lots of callback functions available one of which is eventClick among other that you could use without adding a button. There are a few answers below that show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first off, unless the button is required from UI/UX perspective, you can skip adding the button and just work with fullCalendars built-in method/events.

example (skipping irrelevant options):

```
fullCalendar({
...
editable: true,
selectable: true, // makes each day selectable
select: function (start, end) {
// in this select callback you are given the start and end dates of the user's selection
// when a user selects any cells this will fire and you can do stuff in here
// fullcalendar will always give 2 dates as callback, even if the user only selected 1 
// date, the 'end' will correspond to the next day actually...
events: [{event1},{event2},{event3}], // use this to initialize the events already //existing
eventClick: function (event) {
// this is the handler that will run when the user clicks on an event, not a day! an //event on a day
}
}
})
```

I hope this helps, you can always read more [on the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs)

Comment: this hasn't helped me at all

Comment: Can you show us the whole initialization of your fullcalendar?

Comment: Any chance you are using fullcalendar v1.6.2 ? viewRender was bugged on that version...

Comment: I'm not actually sure, I think I'm using 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

You do not need button ..
you can do it in function  eventClick  this trigger in click on any day

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({

eventClick     : function(xEvent, jsEvent, view){ hus_eventClick(xEvent, jsEvent, view);} ,
});
```

and in function show dialog box to add event ..
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayClick

Comment: this helps a bit but doesn't allow me to add an event

Comment: I would like to add a new event

Comment: you must to create table for it ,